# Arrays present snake matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix

I want to make snake matrix that starts from top left corner,
Without no string.
I dont know how to do it and I need help please.
[Snake matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H9qH.jpg)

Comment: Is there any way to call the function without a string?

Answer (score 0):

This Method in java will generate snake matrix n * m

```java
public static int[][] snakeMatrix(int n, int m) {
    int counter = 1;
    int c = 0;
    boolean isIncrease = true;
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][m];
    for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int x = 0 ; x < n ; x++) {
            matrix[c][i] = counter++;
            if (isIncrease) c++;
            else c--;
        }
        isIncrease = !isIncrease;
        if (isIncrease) c = 0;
        else c = n - 1;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

In your example, the code will be like this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = snakeMatrix(7, 4);
    for (int[] array : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Output

```
[28, 15, 14, 1]
[27, 16, 13, 2]
[26, 17, 12, 3]
[25, 18, 11, 4]
[24, 19, 10, 5]
[23, 20, 9, 6]
[22, 21, 8, 7]
```